# How to Find the Email Address that Couldn't be Delivered to for Email Sent to Multiple Recipients - no.such.address@domain.com

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am sometimes receiving undeliverable email notifications, when we send emails to multiple recipients.

The bounce back email format is

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
no.such.address@some.domain.com
The email address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the recipient's email address and try to resend the message. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.
```

Followed by a lot of technical gook. I've searched through this to find out which of the email addresses was the one that caused the undeliverable report, but it never specifies which one.

Are notifications like these standard, or do the receiver's IT team configure what info actually gets sent in these notifications?

Is there a way of telling which address was the culprit in the technical gook?

Comment: If I needed more information, I would typically look in the headers of the delivery returned email

Comment: what about this one: no.such.address@some.domain.com

Comment: The no.such.address part of that is exactly what I am getting in the email response. The @some.domain.com is made up by me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the address that "no.such.address@some.domain.com" actually displays.

Comment: It isn't that address because it is not in the list of addresses the original email was sent to. Headers confirm this.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know which user failed to receive the email? If so, it's suggested that you could use Message Trace in Exchange to check it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/track-messages-with-delivery-reports?view=exchserver-2019.

Comment: About how to use Message Trace, it's suggested that you could check this thread (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/413340/monitoring-undeliverable-dsn-ndr-for-highly-critic), as Kyle Xu mentioned.